# How can I make my web page resizes with the browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am about to make a personal website / blog for myself but
when I resize the browser window the entire page gets weird.

So how can I make the whole website changed along with the browser window?

**CSS**

```
.länk {
font-family:rockwell;
font-size:300%;
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
}
.margin10px {
margin-top:-10px;
}
.section1 {
margin: auto;
padding: 10px;
max-width:500px;
}
#one {
width: 780px;
float: left;
border-radius:100px;
}
#two {
margin-left: 1300px;
background: #1B6AA5;
border-radius:50px;
}
.länk_sida {
font-family:rockwell;
font-size:150%;
text-decoration:none; 
color:white;
margin-left:-7px;
}
.text {
font-family:rockwell;
font-size:150%;
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
}
body {
background-color:white;
width:auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="button/logga.png"><br>
<div class="margin10px">
<a href="index.html" class="länk">Hem</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a href="blog.html" class="länk">Blogg</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a href="musik.html" class="länk">Musik</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a href="video.html" class="länk">Video</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a href="spel.html" class="länk">Spel</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a href="link.html" class="länk">Länkar</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;<br><br>
</div>

<section class="section1">
<div id="one"><br>
<audio controls></audio><br>
<audio controls></audio><br>
<audio controls></audio><br>
<audio controls></audio><br>
<audio controls></audio><br>
</div>
<div id="two" align="left">
<br>
<div class="text" align="center">Social:</div><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img src="button/giraff/giraff.jpg" width="64" height="64">
<a href="user/liamrabe.html" class="länk_sida">&nbsp;&nbsp;Profil</a><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img src="button/dropdown/facebook-icon.png" width="64" height="64">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/LiamRab3"          class="länk_sida">&nbsp;&nbsp;Facebook</a><br>  
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img src="button/dropdown/twitter-icon.png" width="64" height="64">
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/Liam_Rab3" class="länk_sida">&nbsp;&nbsp;Twitter</a><br>    
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img src="button/dropdown/tumblr-icon.png" width="64" height="64">
<a href="http://www.thenotallowedguy.tk" class="länk_sida">&nbsp;&nbsp;Tumblr</a><br>   
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img src="button/dropdown/youtube-icon.png" width="64" height="64">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/howmuchtimedr" class="länk_sida">&nbsp;&nbsp;Youtube</a><br>    
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img src="button/dropdown/formspring-icon.png" width="64" height="64">
<a href="http://new.spring.me/#!/user/LiamRab3" class="länk_sida">&nbsp;&nbsp;Formspring</a><br><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img src="button/like_.png" width="64" height="64"> 
<a href="#" class="länk_sida">&nbsp;&nbsp;Liam Rabe</a><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: use units in % or try using media queries

Comment: If media queries are not working for you, I doubt class names containing characters outside of range [_A-Za-z0-9] won't work either.

Comment: the used of vw value for font-size could help , some correction : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/crexJ unless you want one and two to sit side by side if enough room

Answer (score 0):

you can use Media Queries or Javascript/jquery

for css media queries do somenthing like:

```
@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 800px){ //you are specifying you want classes inside this rule to change when window is > 0px but < 800px
a{
  color:red;
}
}
```

if you want to use jQuery in this case do somenthing like this:

```
   $(function(){
   $(window).resize(function(){
    var window_width = $(window).width();
    if( window_width < 800 ){ //if window width < 800px do something you want
     alert('Hey the window is '+window_width+'px wide, that is soooo coool');
   }
});
});
```

> Media Queries support for browsers and devices look at
>   http://caniuse.com/#search=media%20queries

Comment: @Liam_Rab3 impossible :D oh no sorry you might using browser that doesn't supports media queries, check http://caniuse.com for more info about support

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're approaching your css wrong for a properly responsive design. Using things like `margin-left: 1300px` will make it nearly impossible for your layout to adapt to the browser window.

There are some great articles [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/) that you might enjoy that would help you to get a fuller understanding.